# How can proxies be added to Praw without using environment variables?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, praw

I'm trying to test out proxies when using Praw module for Python, and have found some information on setting environment variables.  I'm trying to ascertain whether there is a direct way of using proxies as a keyword for additional to the Reddit() initializer?

I've tried looking everywhere for more information about this, and thought that using proxies with Praw would be more widely-documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [configure a custom `Session`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/configuration.html#configuring-a-custom-requests-session), you can accomplish this without environment variables. You need to modify [`Session.proxies`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.proxies).

```
import praw
from requests import Session

session = Session()
session.proxies['https'] = 'https://localhost:3128'
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='SI8pN3DSbt0zor',
                     client_secret='xaxkj7HNh8kwg8e5t4m6KvSrbTI',
                     password='1guiwevlfo00esyy',
                     requestor_kwargs={'session': session},  # pass Session
                     user_agent='testscript by /u/fakebot3',
                     username='fakebot3')
```

Comment: Jarhill, is there any way to confirm the ip address being used by the Praw Reddit instance?  Is there some way to print it out so that I know the correct proxy is being used?

Comment: > is there any way to confirm the ip address being used by the Praw Reddit instance?

I don't believe so.

> Is there some way to print it out

It's not very elegant, but:

`print(reddit._core._requestor._http.proxies)`